# how to set up mailboxes for each of my virtual hosts on Ubuntu Server

Tags: email, virtualhost, postfix-mta, dovecot

Good afternoon,

I have set up three websites on my Ubuntu server.  All are working fine and set up with SSL certificates.

I have set up emails for one of the domains, using Postfix, Dovecot and Thunderbird, and that is going well, sending and receiving emails no problem.  The trouble comes when I try to follow the same instructions to set up emails for the other two domains.

Please could someone tell me if this is possible and, if so, point me towards a good place to start?

Comment: I found an answer.  Asking the right question helps.  Everything I need is here: https://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. Asking the right question helps. Everything I need is here: postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).